# LESS compiler says parameter is undefined

Tags: css, parameters, compiler-errors, less, undefined

In my code I use LESS pattern matching mixins. When I try to pass an argument into my mixin I get an error.

This is my code:

```
.slide(parallax; @bg, @padding) {
    background: url(@bg) 50% 0 fixed;
    height: auto;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
}

.slide(np; @bg, @padding) {
    background-color: @bg;
}

.slide(@_; @bg, @padding) {
    padding: @padding 0;
}

@slide: parallax;
#ghp {
    .slide(@slide; "../images/ghp.png", 12%);
}
```

Upon compilation it throws this error:

> variable @bg is undefined

Why is this error being thrown and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you learned about LESS pattern matching mixins? The answer to both of your questions can be answered if you knew about pattern matching mixins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Quoting Less Website**
>
> If the compiler sees **at least one semicolon** inside mixin call or declaration, it assumes that arguments are separated by semicolons and all commas belong to CSS lists.

The above implies that when you call the mixin in the below format, the mixin call has only 2 values (or parameters). First parameter has the value of `@slide` variable and the second is the entire remaining part (which is `"../images/ghp.png", 12%`).

```
.slide(@slide; "../images/ghp.png", 12%);
```

This is the reason why you get the error saying one of the variables is undefined. This can be overcome by using the same separator (either semi-colon or coma, the preference being semi-colon).

So, for example the below code would compile perfectly fine.

```
.slide(parallax; @bg; @padding) {
    background: url(@bg) 50% 0 fixed;
    height: auto;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
}

.slide(np; @bg; @padding) {
    background-color: @bg;
}

.slide(@_; @bg; @padding) {
    padding: @padding 0;
}

@slide: parallax;
#ghp {
    .slide(@slide; "../images/ghp.png"; 12%);
}
```